# Save HTML to Pdf ABCPdf 4

Tags: abcpdf

I'm using following code to save html to pdf file. But it fails to compile at 
if (!theDoc.Chainable(theID)). I do have using WebSupergoo.ABCpdf4; added at the begining of the code. Is this version issue? Is there any other method to save HTML string to pdf file in ABCPdf 4.

Error Message is "'WebSupergoo.ABCpdf4.Doc' does not contain a definition for 'Chainable' and no extension method 'Chainable' accepting a first argument of type 'WebSupergoo.ABCpdf4.Doc' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
Doc theDoc = new Doc();
theDoc.Rect.Inset(10, 50);
theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage();
int theID;
theID = theDoc.AddImageHtml(str);
while (true)
{
if (!theDoc.Chainable(theID))
break;
theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage();
theID = theDoc.AddImageToChain(theID);
}
for (int i = 1; i <= theDoc.PageCount; i++)
{
theDoc.PageNumber = i;
theDoc.Flatten();
}
theDoc.Save("path where u want 2 save" + ".pdf");
theDoc.Clear();
```

All the help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this. Following is the code to save html string to pdf.

```
Doc theDoc = new Doc(); 
theDoc.Rect.Inset(10, 50); 
theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage(); 
int theID; 
theID = theDoc.AddImageHtml(str); 
while (true) 
{ 
   if (theDoc.GetInfo(theID, "Truncated") != "1") 
    break; 
   theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage(); 
   theID = theDoc.AddImageToChain(theID); 
} 
for (int i = 1; i <= theDoc.PageCount; i++) 
{ 
      theDoc.PageNumber = i; 
      theDoc.Flatten(); 
} 
theDoc.Save("path where u want 2 save" + ".pdf");
theDoc.Clear();
```